# Change user icon style, If the user is logged in. (Angular & Node.js)

Tags: node.js, angular, socket.io, mean-stack, pusher

I am trying to change a user icon to green when the user is logged in, with **Pusher** or with **Socket.io**.

I have managed to do so before, but it was with **SignalR**.
I am now trying to find an alternative with **Angular** and **Node.js**.

This is what I have done with ASP.NET Core SignalR & Angular:
[Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLHNu.png)
(*Porter is logged in on another browser while im logged in with another user, I can see that Porter's user icon is green and not grayed*)

I tried first with **Pusher** and also with **socket.io** but didn't manage to find a solution.

Comment: Please share your code so far to clarify your question and get a better help.

Comment: This video shows exactly what I want to do, but no source code: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MpQBta0amfY